# How to set radio button checked from another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two activities. First activity has different layouts which opens another activity. In another activity I have a segmented group of radio button which I want to set it checked on the basis of the layout is clicked in first activity. To check the radio button I have used this.

segmented5.check(R.id.pickupbakButton);

This sets the button checked but I want it to be checked from another activity on basis of that I have another changes in the layout..

I have first activity like this : [image]

and lets say onClick of PICKUPBOX/BLIND VAN

[image]

It should show radio button of pickupbox/blind van checked.

How can I achieve this??

**GoBoxActivity**

```
public class GoBoxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Intent i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_go_box);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("GO-BOX");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

   final GoBoxPickupActivity gobox = new GoBoxPickupActivity();

   LinearLayout pickupBak = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.PickupBak);
    LinearLayout picupBox = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pickupbox);
    LinearLayout engkelBak = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.engkelBak);
    LinearLayout engkelBox = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.engkelBox);

    pickupBak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GoBoxPickupActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    picupBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GoBoxPickupActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    engkelBak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GoBoxPickupActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    engkelBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GoBoxPickupActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**PickupBoxActivity**

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_go_box_pickup);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
segmented5 = (SegmentedGroup) findViewById(R.id.segmented3);

    segmented5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

 @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.pickupbakButton:

                engkelTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                extraEngkelTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                airConditioning.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                picBoxTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                extraPickBoxTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                return;

            case R.id.pickupboxButton:

                engkelTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                extraEngkelTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                airConditioning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                picBoxTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                extraPickBoxTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                return;

            case R.id.engkelbakButton:

                picBoxTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                extraPickBoxTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                engkelTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                extraEngkelTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                airConditioning.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                return;

            case R.id.engkelboxButton:

                picBoxTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                extraPickBoxTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                engkelTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                extraEngkelTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                airConditioning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                return;
            default:

                engkelTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                extraEngkelTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                airConditioning.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                picBoxTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                extraPickBoxTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you clear it?

Comment: Please check the images added.. @Nigam Patro

Comment: What is segmented group here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code inside onClick in **GoBoxActivity**, as follows

```
i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GoBoxPickupActivity.class);
i.putExtra("selected", 1);
startActivity(i);
```

And in **PickupBoxActivity** , do something like this

```
int selected = getIntent().getIntExtra("selected",1);
```

after that

```
switch(selected)
{
    case 1:
      segmented5.check(R.id.pickupbakButton);
    break;
    case 2:
       .... So on
}
```

Let me know further for any issues..

Comment: Thank you for reply.. I tried this but getting work for only first button not for the rest..@Nigam Patro

Comment: @user5669913 mean you need to add for all 4 buttons, with 4 different values. Not with same value.

Comment: sorry dint get you. :-(